# swap or shuffle Page

Tags: onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

In `myNavigator` at present there are three pages: `bottom.html`, `middle.html`, and `top.html`. I want to get the `bottom.html` above the `top.html` and for that I am calling `pushPage`.

But there are two issues here:

1. The  stack looks like this  `bottom.html`, `middle.html`, `top.html`, `bottom.html`.
2. The new `bottom.html` is fully reconstructed, so it is wasting lots of
   resources in rebuilding the same content.

I tried `resetToPage` function but the issue is still same.

Comment: are you using Onsen UI ? Could you be more specific =) hard to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged Onsen UI 2 then you can use the [**`bringPageTop`**](https://onsen.io/v2/docs/js/ons-navigator.html#method-bringPageTop) method which seems to be doing exactly what you want. ^_^

So you can do either of

- `myNavigator.bringPageTop(0)`
- `myNavigator.bringPageTop('bottom.html')`

Good luck with your app!

Comment: thanks I am using onsenui - v1.3.15. I guess its closer to onset UI 2. Let me try to upgrade.

Comment: Oh, sorry - I saw a tag `onsen-ui2`, so I thought you were using it. If you upgrade it has the exact feature that you want.